# Simulate keyboard input / insert string into textarea (doulingo)

Tags: javascript, html, bots

I'm trying to make a doulingobot, which automatically answers question and learns, to improve my javascript skills. The bot works well on all types of question types but typing in "textarea questions"(HTML below). I can change the value of the textarea and the innerhtml, but as soon as i submit it, it clears itself, but when I type additional text the text also when submited stays. I think it is similar to this problem: [simulate keyboard input / insert string into textarea (adwords)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33063418/simulate-keyboard-input-insert-string-into-textarea-adwords) , but the solutions given dont seem to work.

```
<textarea data-test="challenge-translate-input" class="_2MGCg _1py6s _1e69E _3_NyK _1Juqt" data-gramm="false" dir="ltr" lang="de" placeholder="Auf Deutsch schreiben"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `innerHTML` try `value` to set value

If you want to trigger a key event you can do after setting the value

```
document.querySelector('textarea').dispatchEvent(new Event('keypress'));
```

Comment: I've actually tried most events that could help(keydown,keypress,keyup,mousedown,click) and they didn't work, any other ideas?

Comment: I can't check without an actual test instance.

Comment: i cant send you the html because it wont work other than on their server, but if you have some spare time, i could give you the account im testing on where you could find the "type questions". I would really really appreciate that

Comment: I could check it out, but not sure if you should be sharing the account credentials

Comment: got my comment deleted?