# Fire Events after change of React Textarea's value from Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I got a little Android App with a webview. I want to set a textareas value from there, which seems to be a react object.

It's working so far, I got the handle on the textarea and can set the value by my own javascript-routine. But the triggers are not called, so the form validation gives me an error the field would be empty.

I can manipulate the textarea with

`document.getElementById('textareaId').value = "new value";`

(I found the element by its properties and set the id myself for later use, so no need to tell react possibly isn't using ids)

How can I fire the events on the react objects?

I already tried to fire the events on the textarea itself but that doesn't seem to work. In the browser I see triggers `onchange, onkeyup, onkeydown`  but I can't call them from outside, nor can I display them except from the browsers dev tools.

**Any workaround for this would also be very welcome!**

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be just a matter of the right type of event:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("Events");            
evt.initEvent("change", true, true);                
textarea.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

from this answer [simulate keyboard input / insert string into textarea (adwords)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33063418/simulate-keyboard-input-insert-string-into-textarea-adwords)

did the trick.